# Fulltext search with mysql ignoring # character

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

I wrote a simple diary/journal online application at personaldreamjournal.com. You can login in demo mode to test it using name guest and password user.

It uses the LIKE to do fulltext searching on words in the diary. I wanted to add the ability to allow hashtags for easy tagging of entries. like if someone enters #workout, it returns all the entries with hashtag #workout. But evidently not that easy as it appears to ignore the hashtag. (no idea why they would ignore ANY character in a text box??, but so is life).

So all entries with the word workout is returned as # is ignored. 
I just want confirmation, from what I have searched so far, as nothing specifically mentions the # character.

So im assuming # is a special character that is ignored for some reason?
and that for me to change it I have to alter the MYSQL configuration somewhere? Where exactly for the # character?

Any help confirming what im saying is true, and how to allow for the #character to be counted in return results, is appreciated.

UPDATE:
below is the actual code I was using. so I wasn't using LIKE

```
  $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT *, MATCH(`scroll`.text) AGAINST (+'$searchstring_Recordset1'     IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM scroll WHERE MATCH(`scroll`.text) AGAINST('+$searchstring_Recordset1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) having score > 0.2 AND user = '$username' ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Answer (score 4):

Norman, using the `LIKE` keyword is not using full text searching.  You have to set the text field to have a fulltext index.  (MyISAM tables, I believe)  Then, do something like this:

```
Select * From table Where (MATCH (field) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0);
```

This will give you all results that match.

If you wanted them with a ranking order as well as rank returned, you can do:

```
Select *, (MATCH (field) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) As rank From table Where (MATCH (field) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 0) Order By (MATCH (field) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) Desc;
```

Using the full text search multiple times will not slow down your query, I've read, as MySQL sees that it's the same search and just uses the same results.

Also, if you just want an answer for using the `LIKE` keyword, we'll need to see your original query.

**EDIT**

It looks like this person had the same issue as you and it was resolved.

[MySQL Full-Text search for hashtags (including the # symbol in index)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296870/mysql-full-text-search-for-hashtags-including-the-symbol-in-index)

So using the full text search plus this should be what you need, it seems.

Comment: Thanks James for the awesome response. I am going to implement a version of your code and report back if that suits my needs. Appreciated.

Comment: so @James, it seems like I was already using something similar to what you suggested, which seems like the best practice, likely why I used it :o), now still faced with how to have searches honor hashtag # in searches, as now it ignores it. I have to change something somewhere, not sure what.

Comment: @NormanBird I don't think you can `Order By score` since it is not an actual field.  But can you also `echo` the full query text (with samples in the text areas) for testing?  Also, do you get any errors with the current query?  Or is it just not returning results?  `echo mysql_error()` or `echo mysqli_error()` if using mysqli

Comment: it actually works and does not give an error, so I assumed the score was working. it searches a text field & returns entries from a journal. If I search for a word, all entries with that word is returned. I wanted the Twitter effect with the ability to hash stuff with #. then someone can enter #workout and find an entry with the word workout. but #workout search returns ALL entries with workout and ignores the # character. I checked and the character map is the swedish latin default which includes the ascii character #. So this is were Im at

Comment: @NormanBird Check the edit in my answer.  Looks like someone else was able to get it working using that answer.

Comment: who got it to work?? I just tried and your code just gives me a blank white screen. PHP doesnt like your code. :-)cant get it to even run right. thanks

Comment: to clarify, your ranking order second code didnt work and shows white screen, the first code runs, but ignores the # and gets all 'workout' not just #workout.

Comment: @NormanBird There is a link under **EDIT** in my answer that goes to another question asked about the same thing (how to make it see the # as text instead of a special character).  Their question was answered and accepted as correct.  It should help you as well.

Comment: ok, I see now. I did see that specific article when searching and went to the link it describes at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/character-arrays.html. but although it says alot, it doesnt seem to tell you how to do anything. If that makes sense. Basically, the page didnt help me. when I opened the xml file in question and found the swedish latin map, the ascii character 28 (#) was already listed. So that is what I mean by it says a lot, but I dont get how this is to help MYSQL recognize the letter #, as its already listed. Thats why i reposted.  dont see how that helps. but thanks.

Comment: # is actually ascii character 35.